# Progressbar in C# on double click of .exe

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio-2010, launcher, java-launcher

I have a Java application bundled in ISO image, which has a launcher written in c#.
when i start the application via CD, there is a long wait period, which gives the user wrong notion that the application is not starting. i tried to put a progressbar in java application and call it at the very starting of the program but it failed. So i am trying to launch progressbar in the launcher.

launcher code below

Program.cs

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RunMyprogram
{
static class Program
    {
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.FileName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/myBatFile.bat";
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                Process.Start(startInfo);
}
}
}
```

Please let me know how to add a progressbar in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new thread, on that thread show progress as adding dots. As the application cannot know the status of current execution, we cannot show a progress bar stating how much % is completed.

What you can do is show an endless progress option with a message like "Launching the application, this may take up to 10 minutes..... Thanks for your patience."

The code for this will be like below:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;   // for ThreadStart delegate and Thread class
using System;             // for Console class

namespace RunMyprogram
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(ShowProgress);
                Thread t = new Thread(ts);
                t.Start();

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.FileName = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/myBatFile.bat";
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.Verb = "runas";
                Process.Start(startInfo);

                t.Join();
        }

        static void ShowProgress()
        {
            // This function will only show user that the program is running, like aspnet_regiis -i shows increasing dots.

           Console.WriteLine(""); //move the cursor to next line
           Console.WriteLine("Launching the application, this may take up to 10 minutes..... Thanks for your patience.");

           // 10 minutes have 600 seconds, I will display 'one' dot every 2 seconds, hence the counter till 300
           for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
           {
               Console.Write(". ");
               Thread.Sleep(2000);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

instead of `for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++)` you can also use a `while(true)` (endless) loop, but for that you must be able to know if the second application has launched or not, so that you can have a condition to move out of that endless loop.

Comment: Thanks for the code..can we consider a progress bar without showing percentage.

Comment: do you want a windows form containing a progress bar?

Comment: no...i mean like a indeterminate progress bar as in java

Comment: but they are graphical... let me know what and how you expect in Console based so that I can guide

Comment: My requirement is to have a indeterminate progress bar(as in java) in launcher till it launches the .exe java application

Comment: also i dont want anything to be printed in the console

Comment: your launcher is a C# windows application?

Comment: Yes, it is. Check the OP.
Perhaps adding in a simple Windows Forms window with a [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx) (check Remarks section) with style [Continuous](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) will do?

Comment: @ManishDalal: yes ,its a c# windows application

Comment: if its a C# Windows application, I hope the Main also include the 'Application.Run(new formClassName())' code. I will update my answer

Comment: Add a progress bar on your form and set its Style to Marquee. This will show an indeterminate progress bar.

Comment: I dont have any 'Application.Run(new formClassName())'.

Comment: Also i dont have any form in the launcher code..Please post me code for form integration with progress bar